# OkHttp not sending tokens

Tags: java, html, http, web, okhttp

I have OkHttp & Cookiejar handling all cookies. The instance of my client loads a login page, then responds with credentials and I get a 200 response with 4 cookies:

```
CONTOSO_USER
CONTOSO_INSTANCE
CONTOSO_ANALYTICS
JSESSIONID
```

The issue is that when I make subsequent requests to the server it appears its only sending `JSESSIONID` and `CONTOSO_USER`.

I am my client setup is:

```java
//LOGIN URL
HttpUrl loginUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
     .scheme("https")
     .host("svapp.contoso.com")
     .addPathSegment("wf")
     .addPathSegment("logon")
     .build();

// OTHER STUFF

// COOKIE STORE
CookieStore cookieStore = cookieManager.getCookieStore();

// COOKIE JAR
CookieJar cookieJar = new CookieJar() {
    private final HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url.host());
        return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
    }
};

// NEW CLIENT
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
        .cookieJar(cookieJar)
        .build();

// REQUEST TO LOGIN TO WEBSITE AND RECEIVE COOKIES
```

And then I can print the 4 cookies describe above with:

```java
for (Cookie cookie : cookieJar.loadForRequest(loginUrl)) {
    System.out.println("\n Cookie:" + cookie.name());
    System.out.println("\t Domain:" + cookie.domain());
    System.out.println("\t Value:" + cookie.value());
}
```

Yet when I create a new request with:

```java
Request quickFind = new Request.Builder()
        .url(quickFIndUrl)
        .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), postBody))
        .build();
System.out.println(" Headers : " + quickFind.headers() +"\n") ;
```

It only sends `JSESSIONID` and `CONTOSO_USER`.

The response headers that set the cookies:

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-language: en-
content-length: 0
content-type: ; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 29 Jul 2021 18:40:00 GMT
location: https://svapp.contoso.com/wf/htmlnavigator/launch
pragma: no-cache
server
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxx; domain=svapp.contoso.com;
set-cookie: CONTOSO_ANALYTICS=xxxx; path=/; domain=.contoso.com;secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: CONTOSO_INSTANCE=xxxxx; path=/; domain=.contoso.com;secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: CONTOSO_USER=xxxxx; path=/; domain=.contoso.com;secure; HttpOnly
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that JSESSIONID domain is svapp.contoso.com but the other three cookies domain is contoso.com.

Why?

Comment: Can you include the full set-cookie response header, omitting the cookie value? Also useful if you include the target URL because that's used to determine which cookies are sent.

Comment: Jesse - question updated. Thanks.